Column Validation Problems with LEN and MOD
I have a SharePoint List text field that I'm trying to implement column validation on. I need that field to be:

Only digits and commas
Cannot end in a comma
Each set of digits is 8 characters

The problem is that the comma counts as a character, so anything with a comma and another set of digits doesn't validate properly. So '12345678' validates, but so does '12345678,1234567'.
Here's what I've got so far:
=OR([Vacancy Number(s)]="",AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ",[Vacancy
Number(s)])),OR(ISNUMBER([Vacancy Number(s)]+0),ISNUMBER(REPLACE([Vacancy
Number(s)],FIND(",",[Vacancy Number(s)]),1,"")+0)),LEFT([Vacancy
Number(s)],1)<>",",RIGHT([Vacancy Number(s)],1)<>",", MOD(LEN([Vacancy
Number(s)]), 8) = 0))

Any suggestions on how I should handle this?

What is decimal separator in your regional format - dot or comma? Also you need to define how many integers are allowed after separator. Also also does field should hold one number or many (if many, you need a number separator to be different from decimal separator)?

Unfortunately I need to use a text field for this column. Does the decimal separator matter in this instance?

It can be a text field, but your validator will allow entering only numbers - so we are focusing on validator. My questions are in general - think on paper, from business perspective, not from "how it is stored in SP".
Yes it matters, if you want to store decimal numbers (not round).

I think I understand your comment. So in this case, the comma is a delimiter between groups of numbers (they're IDs in this case). In my region, the decimal separator is a comma, so 1234 is represented as 1,234.

Just to be sure we are on same page - "delimeter separates two groups of integers - both groups together make one number". So yeah - try to understand your business requirements and solution will become obvious (or new question :) )
